# Only defualt values passed to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I'm pretty new to programming and I'm strugling with quite simple "Create" controller and view.

In the view user is declaring values, which should be passed to database. Here's the model:

```
public class Expense

{
    public int ExpenseID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Data")]
    [Column(TypeName = "DateTime2")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Wartość")]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Opis")]
    public string Details { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Rodzaj")]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

}

public class Category
    {
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Expense> Expenses { get; set; }
    }
```

In the same view I want to include partial view for managing the categories (adding, removing).

To have this working I've implemented ViewModel:

```
 public class ExpenseCreateViewModel
{
    public Expense ExpenseCreate { get; set; }
    public Category CategoryCreate { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the code for my View:

```
@model Wydatki2._0.Models.ExpenseCreateViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Dodaj wydatek</h2>


<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        <div>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateExpense", "ExpenseCreate", FormMethod.Post, new { }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <div class="form-horizontal">

                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ExpenseCreate.CategoryID, "Rodzaj", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">

                            @Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ExpenseCreate.CategoryID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ExpenseCreate.Amount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ExpenseCreate.Amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ExpenseCreate.Amount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ExpenseCreate.Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ExpenseCreate.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ExpenseCreate.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ExpenseCreate.Details, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ExpenseCreate.Details, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ExpenseCreate.Details, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>



                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                            <input type="submit" value="Dodaj" class="btn btn-default" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </th>
<th>
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-default" value="Dodaj/Usuń Kategorię" />
        <p class="error">@ViewBag.Warning</p>
    </div>

    <div id="Create" style="display:none">
        @Html.Partial("CreateCategory", Model.CategoryCreate)
    </div> 


</th>
</tr>
</table>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/toggle")
}
```

The problem is that when I submit the form only the CategoryID value is passed correctly. The rest of parameters have just default values. The partial view is working well - I'm able to add or remove categories, which then are passed to the main view.

The code for my Controller:

```
namespace Wydatki2._0.Controllers
{
    public class ExpenseCreateController : Controller
    {
        private WydatkiContext db = new WydatkiContext();




        public ActionResult Create(bool? warn = false)
        {
            ExpenseCreateViewModel model = new ExpenseCreateViewModel()
            {
                ExpenseCreate = new Expense(),
                CategoryCreate = new Category()
            };

            var query = from b in db.Categories
                        where b.CategoryID != 1
                        select b;



            if (warn.GetValueOrDefault())
            {
                ViewBag.Warning = "Nie możesz usunąć tej kategorii.";
            }

            ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(query, "CategoryID", "Name");
            return View(model);
        }



        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult CreateExpense([Bind(Include = "ExpenseID,Date,Amount,Details,CategoryID")] Expense expense)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Expenses.Add(expense);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Create");
            }

            var query = from b in db.Categories
                        where b.CategoryID != 1
                        select b;

            ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(query, "CategoryID", "Name", expense.CategoryID);
            return View(expense);
        }




        public ActionResult CreateCategory()
        {

            return View();
        }




        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult CreateCategory([Bind(Include = "CategoryID,Name")] Category category)
        {


            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Category cat = db.Categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name== category.Name);



                if (cat != null)
                {
                    if (cat.CategoryID == 1 || cat.CategoryID ==2)

                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Create", new { warn = true });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        db.Categories.Remove(cat);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        return RedirectToAction("Create");
                    }
                }

                else
                {

                    db.Categories.Add(category);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    return RedirectToAction("Create");
                }
            }

            return View(category);
        }
```

I'm inclined to believe that the problem is caused by the model, which I'm passing to the view, but I really don't know, how to pass it correctly... Anyone could help with this?

Comment: You have multiple issues. The main one being your model in the view is `ExpenseCreateViewModel` so that is what the model in the POST method needs to be (unless you use the `Prefix` property of `BindAttribute`). Its difficult to understand what your trying to do here. Your partial is not inside the form tags so what is the point of it?

Comment: Inside my partial view there is another form for adding or removing a category. User can go to this view by pressing toggle button, which shows/hides the partial view. I still don't know how to pass the right model to the `CreateExpense` Post action.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
([Bind(Prefix="prefixhere")]Category category)
```

I assume your prefix should be `CategoryCreate` for category, which the extension from your model `ExpenseCreateViewModel`, same for your CreateExpense, your prefix should be `ExpenseCreate`, this way you tell your controller to expect your input names after this prefix, so it will look for `CategoryID and Name` in create category action after the prefix you passed.

Something Like this

```
([Bind(Prefix="CategoryCreate")]Category category)
([Bind(Prefix="ExpenseCreate")]Expense expense)
```

Comment: `CategoryCreate` works fine, as I'm passing the right model in `@Html.Partial("CreateCategory", Model.CategoryCreate)`. The `ExpenseCreate` post action is not working properly. When I added `Prefix` I got this exeption: SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Expense_dbo.Category_CategoryID". The conflict occurred in database "WydatkiDatabase", table "dbo.Category", column 'CategoryID'.